# ArrayQueue -> RandomQueue implementation: Issues excluding a random element

Tags: java, arrays

I'm attempting a problem from Pat Morin's *Open Data Structures* textbook, based on his ArrayQueue implementation:
https://opendatastructures.org/ods-java/2_3_ArrayQueue_Array_Based_.html

"Exercise 2..3 Design and implement a RandomQueue. This is an implementation of the Queue interface in which the remove() operation removes an element that is chosen uniformly at random among all the elements currently in the queue. (Think of a RandomQueue as a bag in which we can add elements or reach in and blindly remove some random element.) The add(x) and $ remove() operations in a RandomQueue should run in constant time per operation."

His code for remove():

```
T remove() { 
    if (n == 0) throw new NoSuchElementException();
    T x = a[j];
    j = (j + 1) % a.length;
    n--;
    if (a.length >= 3*n) resize();
    return x;
}
```

Logically, what I'm trying to do is:

1. Swap a random element and the next element.
2. Return the next element (now swapped with another random element).

I must be missing something, because performing this operation returns some elements multiple times, and never returns others. My code (renamed variables for clarity):

```
    public T remove() {
        if (count == 0) throw new NoSuchElementException();

        Random random = new Random();
        int randIndex = random.nextInt(count);
        T objTemp = array[nextElem];
        array[nextElem] = array[randIndex];
        array[randIndex] = objTemp;

        T obj = array[nextElem];
        // Increment next element:
        nextElem = (nextElem + 1) % array.length;
        // Decrement element count:
        count--;

        if (array.length >= (3 * count))
            resize();

        return obj;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong, here? Why am I getting some elements multiple times, and others not at all?

(Note: This is for an online university course.)

Comment: `array[randIndex]` is not one of the *remaining* values. --- Say you add 30 values, then remove 20 of them. At this time `nextElem = 20, count = 10`. Remaining values are at indexes 20-30, but you calculate `randIndex` in range 0-10, i.e. pointing to previously returned values. *Oops!*

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Andreas for pointing out my silly mistake.

I needed to get my index based on the index of the head (of course!). This code works:

```
    public T remove() {
        if (count == 0) throw new NoSuchElementException();

        Random random = new Random();
        int randIndex = random.nextInt(count);

        int safeRandomIndex = (headIndex + randIndex) % array.length;

        // Swap that randomly chosen element with our nextElem:
        T objTemp = array[headIndex];
        array[headIndex] = array[safeRandomIndex];
        array[safeRandomIndex] = objTemp;

        T obj = array[headIndex];
        headIndex = (headIndex + 1) % array.length;

        count--;

        if (array.length >= (3 * count))
            resize();

        return obj;
    }
```